# How can I make three20 remember my scroll position in a table view?

Tags: objective-c, three20

In three20, when I open a table view, scroll down a bit, click the
back button, and then go back into that same table view, three20 does
not seem to automatically remember my scroll position. It puts the
scroll back at the top.

How can I make three20 remember where I was? I'm assuming it destroys
the view controller once I leave it. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no clue how three20 works. But the basic idea with UISrollView would be to just store the scroll point in a variable and then when the view is reloaded set the scroll point.

```
contentOffset
setContentOffset:
```

Comment: Thanks @Avizzv92 but this really is more of a three20 question. The problem is when the three20 navigator object leaves a view in a navigation controller, it appears to destroy the view. I want to know how to make it *not* do that. My question also applies to more generic views than just tables view and scrolling, e.g., if I open up a MKMapView, leave, then come back I want the user to be looking at the same region.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is just part of the way three20 functions. The only way to make this work is to override the `dealloc` method and save the scroll position at that time. Then, when reinitializing it, load that saved information and go from there.